# Why does this simple C program crash at runtime?

Tags: c, string, pointers, runtime-error, strcat

I tried the following simple C program but it crashes at runtime without giving any output. What is wrong here? How can I solve this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char *s1="segmentation";
    char *s2="fault";
    char *s3=strcat(s1,s2);
    printf("concatanated string is %s",s3);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this is the agregated answer for this question:

you *should not* try to alter string literal in any way. according to the C standard , altering string literals causes *undefined behaviour*:

> "It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined."

but let's say for the discussion that s1 is not string literal - you still need have enough buffer for strcat to work on - strcat finds the nul termination character and start writing on it the string you're appending. if your buffer is not big enough - you will try to write outside the bounderies of your array - causing again undefined behaviour.

Comment: I think it's the contrary, you append the 6 character of "fault" o the 13 of "segmentation "

Comment: You should probably mention that trying to modify string literals in any way is undefined and will likely cause a crash (the answer currently implies that the only problem with OP's code is insufficient space)

Comment: can you give a source for that ? as far as I know (and I might be wrong) it is ok to alter string literals as long as you keep the "regular" C-string manipulation rules (not exceeding the boundry etc.). all the string literals are basically char arrays you allocate on the Data segment.

Comment: @DavidHaim Modifying a **string literal** is NOT OK.

Comment: OK, I agree with you guys, please give some sort of formal documentation so we can append it to the answer.

Comment: @DavidHaim: [Online C 11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.5.2/7: "It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
appropriate values. **If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
undefined.**"

Comment: added to the answer . I guess there's a reason I quitted C in favor of C++ : - )

Comment: @DavidHaim, this all mess could be prevented if the char pointers were defined as `const` - as they should be defiend. Defining constant read-only strings without `const` is an invitation for bugs - this is the main root for the issues here, not the allocated space. `strcat()` is not the only modification to fail here, but any other modification of this string will also fail - e.g. `s1[0] = 'h'` will fail too! Because `s1` points to read-only memory!

Comment: In my opinion, you should change your answer - it should start with the read-only problem. Only then you should talk about the allocation size. I think you should do it especially as your answer seems to be the most popular here. Other people would use your answer as a reference

Answer (score 3):

Because strcat append functions on his first argument.
Ie the result will be store on s1 not on s3

You should allocate more memory for s1.
Ie :

```
 char* s1 = malloc(sizeof(char) * (13 + 6)); //length of your 2 strings
strcpy(s1, "segmentation");
char *s2="fault";
strcat(s1,s2);
printf("concatanated string is %s",s1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Others are focusing on there is not enough space in `s1` for string concatenation. However, the bigger problem here is you are trying to modify a **string literal**, which is undefined behavior. Defining `s1` as a char array that has enough space should work:

```
char s1[20] = "segmentation";
char *s2 = "fault";
strcat(s1,s2);
printf("concatanated string is %s",s1);
```

Comment: Also mention that `strcat` modifies the first argument, so `s3` is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

`char *s1="segmentation";`

`s1` is an immutable string, which will be reside in `read-only` memory. If you look at the `strcat` definition:

`char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src)`  [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcat.htm)

`dest` -- This is pointer to the destination array, which should contain a C string, and should be large enough to contain the concatenated resulting string.

so when you are calling `char *s3=strcat(s1,s2);` you are trying to modify the immutable string which result in segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

The most problematic thing here is that you declared `s1` and `s2` as `char *` and not as `const char*` - always use `const` in such case - this is **read-only** memory when you initialize a string this way.

If you want to extend the string in s1, you should not initialize it as you did, but you should allocate the memory for `s1` on the stack or in the dynamic memory.

Example for allocating on the stack:

```
char s1[100] = "segmentation";
```

Example for allocating in the dynamic memory:

```
char *s1 = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(s1, "segmentation");
```

I used here **100** as I assume that this is enough for your string. You should always allocate a number that is at least the length of your string + 1

Comment: char* s1=malloc(100) is sufficient, because sizeof(char) is always 1. so need  to write sizeof(char).

Comment: I know it, but I always use `sizeof`, including `sizeof(char)`, as I think it is a good practice for remembering to do it each time (when the size is more than 1 byte) :) And seriously, I am pretty sure that in case of `char` the compiler optimizer removes this function call, so it does not take extra computation time

Comment: Anyway - the `sizeof()` is not the most important part in this answer. The important part is to always use `const` when you initialize a char-pointer with a string, because it is really read-only. If you had declared it as `const`, you would not have even tried to `strcat()` into it

Answer (score 1):

Found a similar one here on [comp.lang.c](http://c-faq.com/malloc/malloc2.html)  It also answers in depth.

> the main problem here is that space for the concatenated result is not
>   properly allocated. C does not provide an automatically-managed string
>   type. C compilers allocate memory only for objects explicitly
>   mentioned in the source code (in the case of strings, this includes
>   character arrays and string literals). The programmer must arrange for
>   sufficient space for the results of run-time operations such as string
>   concatenation, typically by declaring arrays, or by calling malloc.
>
> **strcat()** performs no allocation; the second string is appended to the
>   first one, in place. The first (destination) string must be writable
>   and have enough room for the concatenated result. Therefore, one fix
>   would be to declare the first string as an array:
>
> The original call to strcat in the question actually has two problems:
>   the string literal pointed to by s1, besides not being big enough for
>   any concatenated text, is not necessarily writable at all.

Answer (score 0):

look at the definition of `strcat()`

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src)
```

> dest -- This is pointer to the destination array, which should contain a C string, and should be large enough to contain the concatenated resulting string.
>
> src -- This is the string to be appended. This should not overlap the destination.

`s1` is **not enough** to hold the concatenated string, which cause to write beyond the limit. It causes the run-time failure.

try this,

```
char *s1="segmentation";
char *s2="fault";
char* s3 = malloc(sizeof(s1) + sizeof(s2));
strcpy(s3, s1);
strcat(s3, s2);
```